# Cant remove snap atom in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: snap, atom

I am trying to remove Atom snap package from Ubuntu 22.04 with

`sudo snap remove --purge atom`

but I get the error message

```
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Remove data for snap "atom" (286) (failed to remove snap "atom" base directory: remove /var/snap/atom: directory not empty)
```

What I should do?
Below the snap version

```
snap    2.58
snapd   2.58
series  16
ubuntu  22.04
kernel  5.15.0-58-generic
```

Thanks